# Dynamically setting image in underscore template

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, templates, underscore.js

I'm currently using underscore templates to render a HTML list that displays a list of contacts.

The template looks something like this:

```
<li>
 <span class="name">Name: <=%data.name%></span>
 <span class="email">Name: <=%data.email%></span>
 <img class="avatar" src="<=%data.avatar%>"></img>
</li>
```

The issue is, when I set the template data, the source of the image won't be known. Why? Because my data looks something like this:

```
contact = {
  name: string, // i.e. 'John Doe'
  email: string, // i.e 'john@doe.com'
  avatar: string // i.e. '11a93150-14d4-11e3'
}
```

The avatar is actually not a URL, rather a link to a remote database that needs fetching. Something like:

```
function getAvatar(uuid, cb) { // uuid is something like 11a93150-14d4-11e3
 window.db.getImageUrl(function(url) {
  cb(url); // url is something like http://foo.com/avatar.png
 });
}
```

Question is, is there a way to write my template so that instead of reading the avatar value of the contact object directly, I can embed a reference to a function like getAvatar that when the template is rendered, fetches the url to the image and sets the avatar image URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,

Here's an attempt to what I think is the way to go:
http://jsfiddle.net/8EKmC/

I still haven't figured out once I have the URL, how to get hold of the element and set it's src attribute. When the template is being formed, unfortunately, it knows nothing about the DOM :o

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/UySWz/) to demonstrate how you can call JavaScript functions and asynchornously update `src` attribute of thumbnails. I've tried to simulate your DB call using `setTimeout` and the DB using associative array.

**HTML:**

```
<script type='text/html' id='contactTemplate'>
    <li id="contact-<%= avatar %>"> 
     <span class = "name"> Name: <%= name %> </span>
     <span class="email">Name: <%= email %></span> 
     <img class = "avatar" data-populate-path="<% getPath( avatar ) %>" />
    </li>
</script>
<ul id='contactList'></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var contacts = [
    {name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', avatar: '11a93150-14d4-11e3'}, 
    {name: 'Hannah Smith', email: 'hannah@smith.com', avatar: '11a93150-14d4-1231' }
],

simulatedDB = [];
simulatedDB['11a93150-14d4-11e3'] = "path to avatar 1";
simulatedDB['11a93150-14d4-1231'] = "path to avatar 2";

$(document).ready(function () {
    var compiled = _.template($("#contactTemplate ").html());

    _.each(contacts, function (d, i) {
        $("#contactList").append(compiled(d));
    });
});
function getPath(target) {
    setTimeout(updateAvatar, 1000, target);
}
function updateAvatar(target) {
    $("#contact-"+target+" img").attr("src", simulatedDB[target]);
}
```